# Tangent space of algebraic variety at a point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Could you please help me with this problem?

> [Springer, Linear algebraic group, 4.1.9]Assume that $X$ is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^n$, $k$ is an algebraically closed field,
> Describe the tangent space $T_{x} X$ in the following cases:
>
> (a) $X$ is a point;
>
> (b) $X=\mathbb{A}^{n}$, $x$ is an arbitrary point in $X$;
>
> (c) $X=\left\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{A}^{2} \mid a b=0\right\}$, $x=(0,0)$;
>
> (d) Assume that $\operatorname{char}(k) \neq 2,3, X=\left\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{A}^{2} \mid a^{2}=b^{3}\right\}$, $x=(0,0)$.

We have $T_x X \cong (M_x / M_x^2)^*$, where $M_x\subset k[X]$ is the maximal ideal of functions vanishing in $x$. So we need to compute $M_x$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to compute $M_x$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer I don’t know how to compute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give an example computation for one of them.

Take $c$, for example. Here the coordinate ring of the variety is $R=k[a,b]/(ab)$, and the point has maximal ideal $M_x=(a,b)$, since it is $(0,0)$.

We want to first compute $M_x/M_x^2$. So let us see what is inside $M_x^2$. Since $M_x$ is generated by $a,b$, $M_x^2$ is generated by $a^2$, ab and $b^2$. But $ab=0$ is zero in $R$, so $M_x^2$ is generated by $a^2$ and $b^2$.

Now, what does elements of $M_x$ look like? As a $k$-vector space it is spanned by $a, b, a^2, b^2, a^3, ...$. Elements of $M_x^2$ on the other hand are combinations of $a^2, b^2, a^3, ...$

So modding out by $M_x^2$, we are left with $a, b$ inside $M_x/M_x^2$.

We conclude that $T_x \simeq k^2$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your help!